# Calling keyboard Event in subscribe method of ViewChildren & set focus on type in Angular2 typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, keyboard

How can I call Keyboard Event on subscribe in ViewChildren used in button dropdown ul li (which is nested)

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

import { Component, ElementRef, Renderer,ViewChildren,QueryList,AfterViewInit,OnChanges} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpCarService} from './service/vservice';
import {Request} from './model/locationrequest.model';
import {Location} from './model/location.model';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: '/app/view/loc.html',
    providers: [HttpCarService]
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnChanges{

    public result: string;
    public result1: Location[];
    public result2: Location[];
    public result3: Location[];
    public check: boolean;
    @ViewChildren('seidropdown')
     seidr: QueryList<Location>;
     key: KeyboardEvent;

    selectedLCItem = 'Select an Item';
    public isLocationContextSelected: Boolean;

   setFocus(renderer:Renderer){
      this._renderer.invokeElementMethod(
                    this.element.nativeElement, 'focus', []);
                return;                 
   }

    ngAfterViewInit(){
     this.seidr.changes.subscribe((KeyboardEvent.bind(this.setFocus(this._renderer),this.result1)));
    }
    ngOnChanges(){
    }        

    constructor(httpCarService: HttpCarService, element: ElementRef, public _renderer: Renderer) {
        let request = new Request(false, false, true, true, true, true);

        httpCarService.getCarsRestful1(request).subscribe(data => this.result1 = data,
            err => console.log('ERROR!!!'),
            () => console.log('Got response from API', this.result1)
        );

        this.element = element;
    }

    processSelectedContext(item: string) {
        this.selectedLCItem = item;
        this.isLocationContextSelected = true;
    }

    public element: ElementRef;

    public inputEvent(e: KeyboardEvent, isUpMode: boolean = false): void {
        let index = 0;

        alert('Slice value:' + this.result1.length);
        console.log('Key Value' + e.key);
        this.seidr.changes.subscribe(e.currentTarget.addEventListener(this.setFocus()));
      this.setFocus(this._renderer);
    }

    public inputEvent1(e: KeyboardEvent, isUpMode: boolean = false): void {
        let index = 0;

        let e1 = this.element.nativeElement.getElementsByTagName('a');
        for (index = 0; index < e1.length; index++) {
            let a1 = e1[index].innerHTML.charCodeAt(0);
            let a2 = e1[index].innerHTML.charCodeAt(1);
            let a3 = e1[index].innerHTML.charCodeAt(6);
            let a4 = e1[index].innerHTML.charCodeAt(50);

            while (e.keyCode === a1) {
                this._renderer.invokeElementMethod(
                    e1[index], 'focus', []);
                return;
            }
            while (e.keyCode === a2) {
                this._renderer.invokeElementMethod(
                    e1[index], 'focus', []);
                return;
            }
            while (e.keyCode === a3) {
                this._renderer.invokeElementMethod(
                    e1[index], 'focus', []);
                return;
            }
            while (e.keyCode === a4) {
                this._renderer.invokeElementMethod(
                    e1[index], 'focus', []);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here I'm able to achieve keyboard focus event using direct DOM interaction by calling `getElementBytag` which  can result in tight coupling in angular2.

Comment: What does "call" mean? Do you want to fire an event or listen to an event?

Comment: Hi @GünterZöchbauer..... m trying to call keyboard event on bootsrap button dropdown nested ul li  ....and firing a keyboard event it will focus on  dropdown ul li which is in nested structure (heirarchical)

Comment: But what does "call" mean?

Comment: My current keyboard Event call looklike below :

Comment: Call means .....i'm trying to fire an keyboard event which should match with button dropdown ul li  and focus on the list ....here list are heirarchical  order...are in nested form

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to update here... I had wrote a solution  using a directive...
As it's not quite possible to access the nodelist of HTMLElement without using elementRef ...
Have implemented the directive with some  help of  ng2-bootstrap..
https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap/blob/development/components/dropdown/dropdown-keyboard-nav.directive.ts